# How to confirm that party member hasn't been replaced or charmed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, mind-control

How can my PC confirm that the other PCs haven't been replaced by a shapechanger such as an incubus or doppelganger, and haven't been charmed/controlled in some way to work against the party?

One idea is have a password/code to check for shapechangers, but that only goes so far as if a PC is controlled but not replaced they would know the code.

Ideally answers would be methods a Bard could use.

Comment: Would you count *moonbeam* dealing extra damage as a workable method? It arguably involves meta-gaming and I'm not sure how your table feels about that

Comment: I would prefer methods that don't involve damaging the character I'm trying to check, in case they aren't being controlled.

Comment: Related: [How can characters/players identify that a polymorphed dragon is a dragon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/151408/52137)

Comment: How do you know you aren't the one who has been replaced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to be of high enough level to cast these spells, but they should be all you need:

1. [True seeing](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/True%20Seeing#content). This spell gives you truesight which lets you see
   the true form of a shape changing creature.
2. [Identify](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Identify#content). This spell can tell you what, if any, spells are in
   effect on a creature so any spell based charm or domination effects
   will become known to you.
3. [Detect Thoughts](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Detect%20Thoughts#content). This spell literally lets you know what
   thoughts are going through a creature's mind.
4. [Detect Magic](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Detect%20Magic#content). Identify can only ID actual spells, but this spell can tell you if any magical effect is active on the creature. If the target can't explain an active magic upon themselves then you have the right to be suspicious.

Comment: *zone of truth* may also be an option

Comment: I will note that none of these options protect you against a Vampire's Charm. That is not a spell or transformation, nor does the victim know they are Charmed. At best, Detect Thoughts may pick up on positive thoughts towards something that should be an enemy.

Comment: @guildsbounty Good point. I'll add detect magic since the vampire's charm ability is magical.

Comment: Would Detect Magic detect a magical effect being active on a shape changed creature?

Comment: @Shay if the nature of the shapechange is explicitly magical, then yes. e.g. [Doppelgangers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/doppelganger) have non-magical shapechanging: "The doppelganger can use its action to polymorph into a Small or Medium humanoid..." [Dragons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ancient-gold-dragon) have magical shapechanging: "The dragon magically polymorphs into a humanoid or beast..."

Comment: Of course, this isn't terribly helpful if it's the party caster that gets replaced/dominated...

Comment: Nystul's can mask the charm so be wary of that.