# Is a 10th-level Transmutation wizard considered a shapechanger for the purpose of effects such as Moonbeam?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, wizard, shapeshifting

Spells such as [Moonbeam](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/moonbeam) specifically affect creatures with the "Shapechanger" tag, such as lycanthropes. As per [this previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87934/are-druids-shapechangers-for-the-purpose-of-a-polymorph-spell-saving-throw), the ability to change one's shape through class features is not sufficient to be considered a shapechanger.

However, upon reaching the 10th level, transmutation specialist wizards literally receive the "Shapechanger" class feature, granting them the ability the polymorph themselves with greater ease. This feature's description is obviously adapted for player characters, but is otherwise similar to the "shapechanger" feature found in the stat blocks of creatures with the shapechanger tag.

In this context, would possessing the "Shapechanger" feature through the wizard class mark you as a "shapechanger" for the purpose of spells such as Moonbeam?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### According to Jeremy Crawford, yes

In his [tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/723579273936695296)

> A creature must be designated—with a tag or other text—as a shapechanger to count as one.

Transmutation wizard meets this requirement - "other text" - by having the Shapechanger class feature.

### However,

I agree with [Zso's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/96255/40999) on your linked question. Shapechanger has always been an inherent non-magical ability. Transmutation wizards 'shapechange' by means of the *polymorph* **spell**, so I believe the Shapechanger class feature should **not** cause the wizard to count as a Shapechanger, which is exclusively a tag given to monsters.

Answer (score 15):

#### No, a transmuter wizard is not considered a shapechanger

Shapechanger is a [tag](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/introduction#Tags) which is given to certain creatures.

The spell text of [Moonbeam](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/moonbeam) refers specifically to 'A shapechanger' not simply 'A creature with the shapechanger abilty'. Gaining your 10th level class feature as a Wizard Transmuter doesn't change you from a *Medium humanoid (any race)* to a *Medium humanoid (any race, shapechanger)*.

A PC's class features are more akin to NPC's [special traits](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/introduction#SpecialTraits), than to [tags](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/introduction#Tags). Further, spells tend to refer to suitable targets, by tag rather than ability. See for example [Hold Person](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spells#HoldPerson) (which targets 'humanoid's - a tag not an ability) and [Hold Monster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spells#HoldMonster) which excludes 'undead' (a tag not an ability).

See, for comparison, the stat blocks for actual shapechangers - [Doppelganger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/doppelganger) and [Quasit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/quasit) as opposed to the stat block for a creature like the [Couatl](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-c#Couatl) which can simply change shape.

---

Credit is due to [Dale](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/6203/dale-m) for his answer on [this related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87934/40921).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96022/discussion-on-answer-by-tiggerous-is-a-10th-level-transmutation-wizard-considere).