# Are UA Changelings immune to the Polymorph spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, unearthed-arcana, shapeshifting

The [*Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell says:

> This spell transforms a creature that you can see within range into a new form. An unwilling creature must make a Wisdom saving throw to avoid the effect. The spell has no effect on a shapechanger or a creature with 0 hit points.

Changelings (from the original version of *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*, as they appear in [UA: Eberron Races](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/723UA_EberronRaces7232018.pdf)), which are similar to doppelgangers, are able to change appearance, but don't seem to be explicitly shapechangers.

Are UA changelings actual shapechangers and therefore immune to *Polymorph*?

Comment: Yes, I would rather that this question would be solely about the UA / WGtE version, now that Eberron: RftLW is out. And thank you for the notice on the updated polymorph description. The question is now changed accordingly.

Comment: Obviously very related but not a duplicate, about the final version of the race: [Are unwilling Changeling PCs from “Eberron: Rising from the Last War” now immune to the Polymorph spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/160387/are-unwilling-changeling-pcs-from-eberron-rising-from-the-last-war-now-immune)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### No, they are not shapeshifters

Changelings can only change their general appearance, they can't completely change their form. No matter what form they take with their powers they are always a humanoid. They lack the shapeshifter descriptor which would be the main indicator.

Comment: +1; see also [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87934/15469).

Comment: I think you mean "shapechanger" instead of "shapeshifter"  (especially since Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron says  "Changeling. A race of shapeshifters found in Khorvaire")

Comment: Note: per the linked question, the fact that their racial trait is now named "Shapechanger" now makes them qualify as shapechangers. That said, this answer is correct for the version of the changeling this question is asking about.